# Jest, How to mock a function inside an object?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, firebase-authentication, jestjs

I have an function that will call to Firebase and `getIdToken` function

```
export const getUserFromDb = async () => {
  const path = "/user";
  const firebaseToken = getAuth().currentUser?.getIdToken(); // here need to get it
  
  console.log(firebaseToken)
  const myInit = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `token ${firebaseToken}`,
    },
  };

  return API.get(path, myInit);
};
```

How can I mock this line of code?

```
const firebaseToken = getAuth().currentUser?.getIdToken();
```

**For details:**

`getAuth()` is a method which will return a `Auth` object from Firebase.

`currentUser` is a property from `Auth` object, with `User` type.

`getIdToken()` is a method from `currentUser`, which will return `Promise<string>`

Therefore this is what I tried.

**What I have tried:**

I have mock `getAuth()` at the beginning of test file, `getAuth()` is a function, so is `jest.fn()`.

jest.mock("firebase/auth", () => {
return {
getAuth: jest.fn()
}
}

Then in one of my Test case, I tried this:

```
it("should login success and setUser", async () => {

    (getAuth as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValueOnce({
        currentUser: {
            getIdToken: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce('abc')
        }
    })

    // other stuff here
}
```

As you can see, I mock `getAuth()` function to return a `currentUser` object. Then `getIdToken()` function is inside `currentUser` object which will return a string.

But when I run the test, I get this error:

> console.log
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentUser' of undefined

It stated that `currentUser` is undefined. But since I `mockResolvedValueOnce` at the beginning of the test, but it still cant get the `currentUser` value.

**Question**

How can I mock this function? And what I doing wrong?

```
const firebaseToken = getAuth().currentUser?.getIdToken();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up I mock it like this:

```
(getAuth as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue({
      currentUser: {
        getIdToken: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce("abc"),
      },
    });
```

Which is `getAuth` will return a `currentUser` object, inside `currentUser` object have a `getIdToken` function which will return "abc" as  value.

Then when "in my actual code file" called like this:

```
const firebaseToken = getAuth().currentUser?.getIdToken();
```

But the value of `firebaseToken` received in "Test file" will be `abc`, since we already mock the value above. In test file, it wont call to actual Firebase method, instead it will call to the method I mocked above and get the value back.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
const getAuth = jest.fn(() => ({
  currentUser: {
    getIdToken: () => 32,
  }
}));
```